# Python ImportError associated with Python3.5 Installation and Extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, installation, f2py

In attempting to install a Python package from [GitHub](https://github.com/darothen/py-mie) for performing aerosol radiative calculations (not important). After cloning the repo and installing from source (`python3 setup.py install`), I tried to import the library (Python3.5.1) resulting in an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mie._mie'
```

Looking at the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/darothen/py-mie/blob/master/setup.py) file, I noticed that it creates this reference using the Extension syntax. What should I look for in trying to fix/debug this issue?

Why would the package install successfully but not import correctly?

**NOTE**: The extension essentially just wraps around some Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Try a straight:

```
import mie
```

If this doesn't work, consider these questions:

> Is it possible you have multiple version of Python installed and are using a different one to try the import?
>
> Are you using virtualenv by any chance?